# Cannot link IIS7 to network outside

Tags: iis-7, sonicwall

I created a new website in IIS manager. The directory links to a folder in C drive, firewall and antivirus softwares are turned off.

Now I could access the website by `/localhost/` on the server computer, OR `http://192.168.1.123` on any computer at local network.

I have a IP address that connects to the outside, say `59.123.456.789`. This address was previously used by another server and worked fine (people could access the webpages in that server via `59.123.456.789`).

I want to connect `59.123.456.789` with `192.168.1.123` such that now people could access the new server (`192.168.1.123`). I used Sonicwall and sets up the linkage between the two IPs. However, when I surf `59.123.456.789` it returns error (111) connection refused.

Why is it so and how may I solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error 111 connection refused message you're getting doesn't look like one that would be generated by IIS, so I'd suggest your issue is on the Sonicwall side of things.

Are you trying to connect to that public IP from an external host, or from within your local network? If you're trying to connect from the local network then there's a good chance that won't work, since many router/firewalls don't support NAT loopback. If you try from an external source do you get the same error message?

If you're already connecting from outside then I'd suggest there's a problem with the port forwarding rules on your Sonicwall. Check that the rules have definitely been setup correctly, and whether there are any other rules on there that still point to the old local server that used to be used with the public IP address (I'm assuming you updated the existing rule rather than creating a new one from your description?).

Answer (score 0):

After linking them to your correct Website folder location, Did you do you bindings correctly? HTTP port 80 must be open, if its from a VM, port 80 must be open. Also do a telnet cmd or terminal command to see if you are at least pinging.